# Specify env variables on Docker image and using PHP file

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, docker-image

How to specify environment variables on my PHP config file, and store them on .env file?

My goal is was to Dockerize a simple PHP script.

--> Authentification details are stored on a file called config.php.

```
<?php 
define('johndoe', array('USERNAME' => getenv('VAR-USER'), 'PWD' => getenv('VAR-PWD')));
```

--> I've created a .env file which is as below:

```
VAR-USER=johndoe
VAR-PWD=johndoesecret
```

--> And once I perform docker run, I specify my file, using a specific flag:

```
docker run -d -p 8181:80 --env-file=.env my-image:latest
```

When I check if the auth is properly done, it seems that these environment variables are not properly transferred to my config.php file...

Am I missing an important point here?

The goal was here that my php file receive my env vars stored on .env file, as specified on my Docker run command.